# Can extern resolve this or what other way can I get around this?

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern

I am refactoring a pretty large code base. In the old way, there are two libraries: `FooFactory` and `BarLib`. `BarLib` depends on `FooFactory` which in turn depends on a lot of `Foo1`, `Foo2`, `Foo3` code etc... when built, `FooFactory` pulls in all the `Foo` dependencies and then `BarLib` can use `FooFactory` to request construction of, say, a `Foo7`. In my refactoring, I am making all the `FooX` guys depend on `FooFactory` (and not the other way around), and register themselves statically if the makefile happens to link them. `BarLib` still depends on `FooFactory` but will only succeed in creating `Foo7` if it was linked and thus registered statically into the `FooFactory`.

I am running into the following problem:

There is a special `Foo14`, which the main factory file `FooFactory.C` in `FooFactory` constructs with a string that `BarLib` sets. The way this works is that `FooFactory.H` exposes a global function called `setString(const std::string&);` and in the `.C` file it has a `std::string theString` variable in an anonymous namespace. Then a method in `BarLib` may or may not use this function to set this string. And in the corpus of `FooFactory.C`, this string is checked during the construction of `Foo14`.

The issue is, with the dependency reversed, all the construction code for the `Foo` guys is kept inside their respective libraries and only summoned if they have statically registered. I have no simple way of passing this `std::string` down to `Foo14` because it abides by a common interface of arguments passed for constructing a `Foo`. If I place the string `theString` in `Foo14.C` then that would force `BarLib` to depend on `Foo14` in order to set it...so I was wondering if I could keep it in `FooFactory.C`, but in `Foo14` declare it as extern and make use of it. Would this work even if `theString` is in an anonymous namespace of `FooFactory.C`? Or would it now have to be a global living in the header? Or what is an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer from another file to a variable defined in an anonymous namespace, see more here: [anonymous namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363684/anonymous-namespace)

Globals don't have to be defined in a shared header. To allow being referenced from other files it's enough for them to be defined not in anonymous namespace and not as static.