# C++ library "internal use only" coding style

Tags: c++, coding-style, encapsulation

I'm writing a library in C++. All classes and global function are declared inside `mylibrary` namespace.
I need to create some classes for internal use only: who will use this library should immediatly notice what classes are not intended to be used outside the library.
Unfortunatly, I cannot use private function, because this will mess up all encapsulation. I cannot use private classes, because internal classes must be accessed by "normal" classes in the same library.

I guess a good way to do this is creating the namespace `mylibrary::internal` and putting all "private" stuff inside it. Is this the right way? Are there other common ways?

Comment: Will this library be open source?

Comment: Your way is a common way.  And not wrong.  :)

Comment: That's the way boost does it, so it's probably a best practice in C++

Comment: "Unfortunatly, I cannot use private classes, because this will mess up all encapsulation." -- clarify?

Answer (score 4):

Use anonymous namespace for your internal functionality. This will ensure that no outside code will be able to link to it. Read more here: [anonymous namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363684/anonymous-namespace)

Comment: The downside here, though, is that encapsulation through anonymous namespaces imposes constraints on source code organization. If the anonymous namespace is defined in source files, then everything that needs the same internal resource must be defined in the same source file.

Comment: I think this is not what I'm looking for, because there are "internal" API: some classes in the same library need to access internal classes.

Comment: Pete Becker is right, I cannot use anonymouse namespace because of code organization in multiple source files.

Comment: That's correct. Anonymous namespaces might require rearrangement of files but it fulfills the requirement in the question. Whether or not it's suitable for your other needs only you can say.

Comment: Disappointing. I just tried this and came here looking for an alternative. This causes insane scrolling with a moderate smattering of interdependent classes.