# Billboarding C++

Tags: c++, matrix, system, particles

I got a code from my teacher that currently shows a 3D globe and a 2D particle system. The camera moves around in circles. The particle system is supposed to face the camera.

According to my lecture notes, I have to multiply the billboard with the inverse of the camera's view matrix. I would love to try that but I have trouble using the variable for the view matrix.

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <Kore/Application.h>
#include <Kore/IO/FileReader.h>
#include <Kore/Math/Core.h>
#include <Kore/Math/Random.h>
#include <Kore/System.h>
#include <Kore/Input/Keyboard.h>
#include <Kore/Input/Mouse.h>
#include <Kore/Audio/Mixer.h>
#include <Kore/Graphics/Image.h>
#include <Kore/Graphics/Graphics.h>
#include <Kore/Log.h>
#include "ObjLoader.h"

#include "Collision.h"
#include "PhysicsWorld.h"
#include "PhysicsObject.h"

using namespace Kore;

// A simple particle implementation
class Particle {
public:
    VertexBuffer* vb;
    IndexBuffer* ib;

    mat4 M;

    // The current position
    vec3 position;

    // The current velocity
    vec3 velocity;

    // The remaining time to live
    float timeToLive;

    // The total time time to live
    float totalTimeToLive;

    // Is the particle dead (= ready to be re-spawned?)
    bool dead;


    void init(const VertexStructure& structure) {
        vb = new VertexBuffer(4, structure,0);
        float* vertices = vb->lock();
        SetVertex(vertices, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0);
        SetVertex(vertices, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        SetVertex(vertices, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1); 
        SetVertex(vertices, 3, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0); 
        vb->unlock();

        // Set index buffer
        ib = new IndexBuffer(6);
        int* indices = ib->lock();
        indices[0] = 0;
        indices[1] = 1;
        indices[2] = 2;
        indices[3] = 0;
        indices[4] = 2;
        indices[5] = 3;
        ib->unlock();

        dead = true;
    }


    void Emit(vec3 pos, vec3 velocity, float timeToLive) {
        position = pos;
        this->velocity = velocity;
        dead = false;
        this->timeToLive = timeToLive;
        totalTimeToLive = timeToLive;
    }

    Particle() {
    }


    void SetVertex(float* vertices, int index, float x, float y, float z, float u, float v) {
        vertices[index* 8 + 0] = x;
        vertices[index*8 + 1] = y;
        vertices[index*8 + 2] = z;
        vertices[index*8 + 3] = u;
        vertices[index*8 + 4] = v;
        vertices[index*8 + 5] = 0.0f;
        vertices[index*8 + 6] = 0.0f;
        vertices[index*8 + 7] = -1.0f;
    }

    void render(TextureUnit tex, Texture* image) {
        Graphics::setTexture(tex, image);
        Graphics::setVertexBuffer(*vb);
        Graphics::setIndexBuffer(*ib);
        Graphics::drawIndexedVertices();
    }

    void Integrate(float deltaTime) {
        timeToLive -= deltaTime;

        if (timeToLive < 0.0f) {
            dead = true;
        }

        // Note: We are using no forces or gravity at the moment.

        position += velocity * deltaTime;

        // Build the matrix
        M = mat4::Translation(position.x(), position.y(), position.z()) * mat4::Scale(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
    }


};


class ParticleSystem {
public:

    // The center of the particle system
    vec3 position;

    // The minimum coordinates of the emitter box
    vec3 emitMin;

    // The maximal coordinates of the emitter box
    vec3 emitMax;

    // The list of particles
    Particle* particles;

    // The number of particles
    int numParticles;

    // The spawn rate
    float spawnRate;

    // When should the next particle be spawned?
    float nextSpawn;

    ParticleSystem(int maxParticles, const VertexStructure& structure ) {
        particles = new Particle[maxParticles];
        numParticles = maxParticles;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxParticles; i++) {
            particles[i].init(structure);
        }
        spawnRate = 0.05f;
        nextSpawn = spawnRate;

        position = vec3(0.5f, 1.3f, 0.5f);
        float b = 0.1f;
        emitMin = position + vec3(-b, -b, -b);
        emitMax = position + vec3(b, b, b);
    }


    void update(float deltaTime) {
        // Do we need to spawn a particle?
        nextSpawn -= deltaTime;
        bool spawnParticle = false;
        if (nextSpawn < 0) {
            spawnParticle = true;
            nextSpawn = spawnRate;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < numParticles; i++) {

            if (particles[i].dead) {
                if (spawnParticle) {
                    EmitParticle(i);
                    spawnParticle = false;
                }
            }

            particles[i].Integrate(deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void render(TextureUnit tex, Texture* image, ConstantLocation mLocation, mat4 V) {
        Graphics::setBlendingMode(BlendingOperation::SourceAlpha, BlendingOperation::InverseSourceAlpha);
        Graphics::setRenderState(RenderState::DepthWrite, false);



        /************************************************************************/
        /* Exercise 7 1.1                                                       */
        /************************************************************************/
        /* Change the matrix V in such a way that the billboards are oriented towards the camera */


        /************************************************************************/
        /* Exercise 7 1.2                                                       */
        /************************************************************************/
        /* Animate using at least one new control parameter */      

        for (int i = 0; i < numParticles; i++) {
            // Skip dead particles
            if (particles[i].dead) continue;

            Graphics::setMatrix(mLocation, particles[i].M * V);
            particles[i].render(tex, image);
        }
        Graphics::setRenderState(RenderState::DepthWrite, true);
    }

    float getRandom(float minValue, float maxValue) {
        int randMax = 1000000;
        int randInt = Random::get(0, randMax);
        float r =  (float) randInt / (float) randMax;
        return minValue + r * (maxValue - minValue);
    }

    void EmitParticle(int index) {
        // Calculate a random position inside the box
        float x = getRandom(emitMin.x(), emitMax.x());
        float y = getRandom(emitMin.y(), emitMax.y());
        float z = getRandom(emitMin.z(), emitMax.z());

        vec3 pos;
        pos.set(x, y, z);

        vec3 velocity(0, 0.3f, 0);

        particles[index].Emit(pos, velocity, 3.0f);
    }


};










namespace {
    const int width = 1024;
    const int height = 768;
    double startTime;
    Shader* vertexShader;
    Shader* fragmentShader;
    Program* program;

    float angle = 0.0f;

    // null terminated array of MeshObject pointers
    MeshObject* objects[] = { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr };

    // null terminated array of PhysicsObject pointers
    PhysicsObject* physicsObjects[] = { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr };


    // The view projection matrix aka the camera
    mat4 P;
    mat4 View;
    mat4 PV;

    vec3 cameraPosition;

    MeshObject* sphere;
    PhysicsObject* po;

    PhysicsWorld physics;


    // uniform locations - add more as you see fit
    TextureUnit tex;
    ConstantLocation pvLocation;
    ConstantLocation mLocation;
    ConstantLocation tintLocation;

    Texture* particleImage;
    ParticleSystem* particleSystem;

    double lastTime;

    void update() {
        double t = System::time() - startTime;
        double deltaT = t - lastTime;
        //Kore::log(Info, "%f\n", deltaT);
        lastTime = t;
        Kore::Audio::update();

        Graphics::begin();
        Graphics::clear(Graphics::ClearColorFlag | Graphics::ClearDepthFlag, 0xff9999FF, 1000.0f);

        Graphics::setFloat4(tintLocation, vec4(1, 1, 1, 1));

        program->set();


        angle += 0.3f * deltaT;

        float x = 0 + 3 * Kore::cos(angle);
        float z = 0 + 3 * Kore::sin(angle);

        cameraPosition.set(x, 2, z);

        //PV = mat4::Perspective(60, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100) * mat4::lookAt(vec3(0, 2, -3), vec3(0, 2, 0), vec3(0, 1, 0));
        P = mat4::Perspective(60, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100);
        View = mat4::lookAt(vec3(x, 2, z), vec3(0, 2, 0), vec3(0, 1, 0));
        PV = P * View;


        Graphics::setMatrix(pvLocation, PV);





        // iterate the MeshObjects
        MeshObject** current = &objects[0];
        while (*current != nullptr) {
            // set the model matrix
            Graphics::setMatrix(mLocation, (*current)->M);

            (*current)->render(tex);
            ++current;
        } 



        // Update the physics
        physics.Update(deltaT);

        PhysicsObject** currentP = &physics.physicsObjects[0];
        while (*currentP != nullptr) {
            (*currentP)->UpdateMatrix();
            Graphics::setMatrix(mLocation, (*currentP)->Mesh->M);
            (*currentP)->Mesh->render(tex);
            ++currentP;
        }



        particleSystem->update(deltaT);
        particleSystem->render(tex, particleImage, mLocation, View);



        Graphics::end();
        Graphics::swapBuffers();

    }

    void SpawnSphere(vec3 Position, vec3 Velocity) {
        PhysicsObject* po = new PhysicsObject();
        po->SetPosition(Position);
        po->Velocity = Velocity;
        po->Collider.radius = 0.2f;

        po->Mass = 5;
        po->Mesh = sphere;

        // The impulse should carry the object forward
        // Use the inverse of the view matrix

        po->ApplyImpulse(Velocity);
        physics.AddObject(po);
    }

    void keyDown(KeyCode code, wchar_t character) {
        if (code == Key_Space) {

            // The impulse should carry the object forward
            // Use the inverse of the view matrix

            vec4 impulse(0, 0.4, 2, 0);
            mat4 viewI = View;
            viewI.Invert();
            impulse = viewI * impulse;

            vec3 impulse3(impulse.x(), impulse.y(), impulse.z());


            SpawnSphere(cameraPosition + impulse3 *0.2f, impulse3);
        }
    }

    void keyUp(KeyCode code, wchar_t character) {
        if (code == Key_Left) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    void mouseMove(int x, int y, int movementX, int movementY) {

    }

    void mousePress(int button, int x, int y) {

    }



    void mouseRelease(int button, int x, int y) {

    }

    void init() {
        FileReader vs("shader.vert");
        FileReader fs("shader.frag");
        vertexShader = new Shader(vs.readAll(), vs.size(), VertexShader);
        fragmentShader = new Shader(fs.readAll(), fs.size(), FragmentShader);

        // This defines the structure of your Vertex Buffer
        VertexStructure structure;
        structure.add("pos", Float3VertexData);
        structure.add("tex", Float2VertexData);
        structure.add("nor", Float3VertexData);

        program = new Program;
        program->setVertexShader(vertexShader);
        program->setFragmentShader(fragmentShader);
        program->link(structure);

        tex = program->getTextureUnit("tex");
        pvLocation = program->getConstantLocation("PV");
        mLocation = program->getConstantLocation("M");
        tintLocation = program->getConstantLocation("tint");

        objects[0] = new MeshObject("Base.obj", "Level/basicTiles6x6.png", structure);
        objects[0]->M = mat4::Translation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        sphere = new MeshObject("ball_at_origin.obj", "Level/unshaded.png", structure);

        SpawnSphere(vec3(0, 2, 0), vec3(0, 0, 0));



        Graphics::setRenderState(DepthTest, true);
        Graphics::setRenderState(DepthTestCompare, ZCompareLess);

        Graphics::setTextureAddressing(tex, U, Repeat);
        Graphics::setTextureAddressing(tex, V, Repeat);

        particleImage = new Texture("SuperParticle.png", true);
        particleSystem = new ParticleSystem(100, structure);



    }
}

int kore(int argc, char** argv) {
    Application* app = new Application(argc, argv, width, height, 0, false, "Exercise7");

    init();

    app->setCallback(update);

    startTime = System::time();
    lastTime = 0.0f;
    Kore::Mixer::init();
    Kore::Audio::init();


    Keyboard::the()->KeyDown = keyDown;
    Keyboard::the()->KeyUp = keyUp;
    Mouse::the()->Move = mouseMove;
    Mouse::the()->Press = mousePress;
    Mouse::the()->Release = mouseRelease;

    app->start();

    delete app;

    return 0;
}
```

There's a comment where the teacher wants us to add the code. 
The variable for the view matrix "View" is in "namespace". I've only ever used namespace as a library but this one doesn't have a name. So how do I use it?

The comment says that we should use matrix V. So I just add V = Inverse View Matrix * Model Matrix to the code and it removes the rotation?

I'm sorry for the stupid questions, it's supposed to be a class for beginners but it's really anything but. The lecture notes aren't very helpful when it comes to the programming part and I only found tutorials for OpenGL or Unity or Direct X and where not using any of it.

Please help me, I need to hand this in until Saturday morning and I've already spent the last two days trying out code and I've got nothing so far!

You can find the whole thing here: https://github.com/TUDGameTechnology/Exercise7

Comment: What do you want an answer to look like? "Here is the code, hope you get full points"? Stackoverflow doesn't do that. You need to ask a specific question such as [What is an anonymous namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363684). Find a (smart) partner and do the homework together, stackoverflow is not the right place for this.

Comment: Honey, I asked two questions: How can I use the variable "View" and if it's right that I just need to multiply the inverse of the view matrix and the model matrix. Where did I ask anyone to do my homework?

Comment: If this would've been my intention, I had posted the entire exercise. This is just a small part of what I need to do.

Comment: Ok. Apparently your question is well received. Hope you get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything special to access an unnamed namespace. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622874/unnamed-namespace-access-rules) explains more.

You are most probably trying to reference `View` within methods that cannot see your namespace because of the order in which they are defined in your file.

This line in your `update` method:

```
particleSystem->render(tex, particleImage, mLocation, View);
```

is already passing `View` into the `render` method.

```
void render(TextureUnit tex, Texture* image, ConstantLocation mLocation, mat4 V)
```

That means that in this case `mat4 v` *is* your camera view.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know^^. What is the model matrix then? I thought it was "M" from the Particle class but I get an error because it's not static.

Comment: @Schokohuetchen Where and how are you trying to use it? `M` is not static so if you are trying to reference it in methods that are not members of `Particle` you will need to access it through an instance of 'Particle'.

Comment: It actually looks like this code removes the rotation but I'm not sure it's an elegant solution: 
`mat4 billboard = mat4::Identity();
        mat4 vInv = V;
        vInv.Invert();
        billboard = particles->M * vInv;`

Comment: @Schokohuetchen careful, particles is an array, so particles->M is only the matrix of the first particle!  Look in the render code at this existing line and think about what it's currently doing.:  Graphics::setMatrix(mLocation, particles[i].M * V);

Comment: That's the problem, I have no idea what it does. This is the kind of code that just pops up without any further explanation. Like I said, the lecture doesn't really cover the programming part. We get the code and that's it.

Comment: @Schokohuetchen It appears to me that for each particle, it's M matrix is being multiplied by the current (unaltered) V(iew) matrix, and the result of that matrix mult is being set as the current matrix for rendering purposes.  So that part is already done.  I think you just need to tweak V to get what you want.  What happens if you set V to it's inverted self?

Comment: @Kik Oh yeah, looks like that already does the trick. Thanks.